# Counting rows in one column but during different dates

Tags: sql

My aim is to count rows that occurred between certain dates several times (day 0 to day 7 and day 0 to day 45). The code is below, so it would be easier to understand what I mean:

```
SELECT d.personal_id, COUNT (d.deliveryID) as Deliveries_7D, COUNT (d.deliveryID) as Deliveries_45D

FROM table_d d

WHERE d.delivered < d.created + 7 * interval '1 day'

GROUP BY d.personal_id

LIMIT 20
```

Undoubtedly, only one of the following COUNTs would work. Tried to create a sub-query, but it fails or returns some non-sense.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Case When` Expression

```
SELECT 
    d.personal_id, 
    COUNT (case when d.delivered < d.created + 7 * interval '1 day' then d.deliveryID end) as Deliveries_7D, 
    COUNT (case when d.delivered < d.created + 45 * interval '1 day' then d.deliveryID end) as Deliveries_45D
FROM table_d d
WHERE d.delivered < d.created + 45 * interval '1 day'
GROUP BY d.personal_id
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery this way

```
select  t1.personal_id, t1.Deliveries_7D, t2.Deliveries_45D
from  (
    select d.personal_id  COUNT (d.deliveryID) as Deliveries_7D
    FROM table_d d

    WHERE d.delivered < d.created + 7 * interval '1 day'

    GROUP BY d.personal_id 

    ) t1  
    inner join  (

    select d.personal_id  COUNT (d.deliveryID) as Deliveries_45D
    FROM table_d d

    WHERE d.delivered < d.created + 45 * interval '1 day'

    GROUP BY d.personal_id 
    ) t2. on t1.personal_id = t2.personal_id
```